# Swagger and Google Guice setup

Tags: guice, swagger, guice-servlet

I'm trying to add swagger to my project. Our setup differs a bit from the sample projects. We use guice and guice-servlet to inject and start our JerseyServletModule.

Today our web.xml looks something like this

```
<web-app ....>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mypackage.MyServletModule</listener-class>
     </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the class MyServletModule looks like

```
public class MyServletModule extends GuiceServletContextListener {
  ...
  @Override
  protected Injector getInjector() {
  JerseyServletModule api = new JerseyServletModule() {
      @Override
      protected void configureServlets() {
        ... 
        bind().to()
        ... 
        serve("/api/v1/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
        }
      };
    return Guice.createInjector(api);
  }
}
```

Where and how should I add swagger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Jersey where to find the Swagger resources like this (where `org.example` is your package containing services):

```java
Map<String, String> params = Maps.newHashMap();
params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "org.example;com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing");
serve("/api/v1/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
```

Also be sure that Swagger is on your classpath. If you're using Maven add:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.9.1</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do You have any sample, configured project on the web?